# EventEmitter seems to work only for one of the parameters

Tags: angular

Angular newbie here. For some reason the serverContents attribute shows up as undefined in the App component. Any ideas what's wrong. Everything compiles fine, but I cannot seem to display the value of serverContents attribute.

See below :
cockpit.component.html :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <p>Add new Servers or blueprints!</p>
      <label>Server Name</label>
      <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="newServerName"> -->
      <input type="text" class="form-control" #serverNameInput>
      <label>Server Content</label>
      <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="newServerContent"> -->
      <input type="text" class="form-control" #serverContentInput>
      <br>
      <button
        class="btn btn-primary"
        (click)="onAddServer(serverNameInput,serverContentInput)">Add Server</button>
      <button
        class="btn btn-primary"
        (click)="onAddBluePrint(serverNameInput,serverContentInput)">Add Server Blueprint</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

cockpit.component.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output,EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { ServerElementComponent } from '../server-element/server-element.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cockpit',
  templateUrl: './cockpit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cockpit.component.css']
})
export class CockpitComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() serverCreated = new EventEmitter<{serverName: string,serverContent: string}>();
  @Output() bluePrintCreated = new EventEmitter<{serverName: string,serverContent: string}>();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  onAddServer(nameInput: HTMLInputElement,contentInput: HTMLInputElement){
      this.serverCreated.emit({
      serverName: nameInput.value,
      serverContent: contentInput.value
    });
  }

  onAddBluePrint(nameInput: HTMLInputElement,contentInput: HTMLInputElement){
    this.bluePrintCreated.emit({
    serverName: nameInput.value,
    serverContent: contentInput.value
    });
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<div class="container">
  <app-cockpit
  (serverCreated) = "onServerAdded($event)"
  (bluePrintCreated) = "onBluePrintAdded($event)"></app-cockpit>
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <app-server-element *ngFor ="let serverElement of serverElements" [srvElement]="serverElement">
        <p>
          <strong *ngIf="serverElement.type === 'server'" style="color: red">{{serverElement.content }}</strong>
          <em *ngIf="serverElement.type === 'blueprint'">{{ serverElement.content }}</em>
        </p>
      </app-server-element>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  serverElements = [{type: 'server',name: 'Testserver',content: 'Just a test !'}];
    constructor(){
      }
    onServerAdded(serverCreated:{serverName: string,serverContents: string}){
    this.serverElements.push ({
    type: 'server',
    name: serverCreated.serverName,
    content: serverCreated.serverContents
      });
    }
    onBluePrintAdded(bluePrintCreated : {serverName: string,serverContents: string}){
    this.serverElements.push ({
    type: 'blueprint',
    name: bluePrintCreated.serverName,
    content: bluePrintCreated.serverContents
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of your problem, for example on stackblitz.

Comment: serverContent VS serverContents..?

Comment: You are right. Changing it to serverContent fixed it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MikeOne please consider adding this as an answer so OP can accept it (goal should be to keep the question from being unanswered and help the community benefit from it)

Comment: @y_nk - considering this was basically just a typo (it happens) - I'm not sure if there is much value in making an answer out of this. I'm just happy Subra was helped with this.